# Azure b2c signup/sign in using mobile number and code(no password)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have following scenario -

Sign up - 
User enters mobile or email,
MFA to mobile or email for verification,
Password is set only if email is used, for mobile signup - no password

Sign in: 
User can sign in using email id/password with MFA
or
User can sign in using mobile/code(sent to user mobile)

This requirement is somewhat similar to [Azure AD B2C - sign up/in using email OR mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453215/azure-ad-b2c-sign-up-in-using-email-or-mobile)

Please let me know, how to achieve phone with code instead of password.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this with Custom Policies. But Azure AD B2C cannot discern whether the user gave a mobile number or email address.

1. Create a [self asserted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) page which asks the user for Email or Phone in a single [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#claimtype) field.
2. Call a [validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile) (VTP) as part of this self asserted technical profile.
3. This VTP will be a [REST API technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) which sends the users input to an API.
4. The API should format the number correctly if its a phone number, eg +4412345678 and send it back with another claim that flags if its an email or phone number.
5. Based off the flag, use a [PreCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#preconditions) with ClaimEquals, on an Orchestration Step which calls Azure MFA Technical Profile. And pass in the formatted claim phone number as an input claim. The user will then do SMS/Phone call and be logged in.
6. Create another Orchestration step with a precondition which handles a flag for email. This one will launch a self asserted page with the email as an input claim. The OutputClaim will be `Verified.Email`, such that the user must do email verification. The user is then logged in.

Have a look at the samples here too:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples