# B2c Custom Policy and Build in Policy Combine - Retrieve Username

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Used build in policy to do signin and signup and username as login. As there is no build in policy to retrieve username so created additional custom policy for login singup and username retrieve , which is working , the problem is the username retrieve only works for username that are created through custom policy user flow and doesn't retrieve username that are created from build in userflow. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701724/issue-with-getting-upn-on-a-federated-azure-ad-b2c-sign-up-custom-policy-flow

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine both built in and custom policies. Built in policies are configurable from UI And these are predefined policies. You can combine two custom policies.

@rbrayb  Thank you for sharing thread link the comment section.

You may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453215/azure-ad-b2c-sign-up-in-using-email-or-mobile) thread as well for some reference on combining custom policies.