# Not Able to provide language support in b2c Custom policies using localization

Tags: azure, localization, azure-ad-b2c

I am using custom policies to enable mobile number authentication in my mobile app.
I have used custom UI files to manage the UI of the policies using blob storage as given in the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom

Now i want to give support to Chinese language for sign in, sign up and password reset policy. for that i am following Microsoft document :
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#set-up-localization

along with some reference document i found on git:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Migration-JIT-sample/B2C_1A_Demo_Base.xml

FYI,
I have used this MS link to get started with custom policies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom
but i wanted mobile authentication instead of email so i made changes as given in this stackoverflow link:
[Can Azure-AD B2C use a mobile telephone number as a username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988815/can-azure-ad-b2c-use-a-mobile-telephone-number-as-a-username)

i am following the exact steps given in the document but when i run the policy it gives me the error as :
One of the request inputs is out of range.

after following the steps it generates url like this:
https://smarthomestgdev.blob.core.windows.net/en/b2cpagelayout/signup.html

the url is correct but it does not render any sign up page and gives blank page.

Can anyone help me solving the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot this? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom

Comment: Seems issue is related to wrongly configured HTML page.  Your given HTML page throwing **OutOfRangeInput** exception. Because of this B2C page become blank. You need to fix HTML page first.

Comment: If you are new to B2C and Custom UI. Start from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#how-do-i-get-started and try creating a basic custom UI page and get start form there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am able solve this problem by creating folder for "en" and "zh-hans" in blob container.

Comment: However, now when I run the custom policy signin